# Javascript: Can array shift and reverse methods not be called in the same line of code?

Tags: arrays, reverse, shift

This single line in javascript:

```
    myarray.reverse().shift().reverse()
```

doesn't seem to work in the same way as the three separate lines

```
    myarray.reverse();
    myarray.shift();
    myarray.reverse();
```

Is this expected? Or is it a bug?
I know I can replace this with

```
    myarray.pop();
```

but that's not the point. I want to understand what is the expected behavior.

I made a small html to demonstrate this:

```
<html> <body>
<button onclick="myFunction1()">Func1</button>
<button onclick="myFunction2()">Func2</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;

function myFunction1() {
    fruits.reverse();
    fruits.shift();
    fruits.reverse();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
}

function myFunction2() {
    fruits.reverse().shift().reverse();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
}

</script> 
</body> </html>
```

I expected both Func1 and Func2 to act the same way., but the Func2 button doesn't work as expected, although Func1 does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot just chain method calls like that in JavaScript. The later calls will be invoked on the return value of the previous call, not on the original object.

`myArray.shift()` returns the (formerly) first element of the array. It does not return the (original or the modified) array (`reverse` does return the array after updating it in-place).

So `myArray.shift().reverse()` reverses the first element.

Whereas `myArray.shift(); myArray.reverse();` first removes the first element and then reverses the rest of the array.